# Happy Lunar New Year or Happy Chinese New Year?

Tags: chinese-new-year

請問各位傾向說哪個 ?

農曆在亞洲社會較為多為華人慶祝

Happy Lunar New Year much more like for all country celebating New Year ?

Or perfer Chinese New Year ?

農曆新年快樂比較適合還是中式新年快樂 ?

The last one sounds weird in Chinese ?

Since in western country much more percentage says Happy Lunar New Year than Happy Chinese New Year.

也祝在站上的各位，新春愉快，虎年行大運 ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"農曆在亞洲社會較為多為華人慶祝". This sentence is vague, I'll change it to:

亞洲社會華人**大多**慶祝農曆**年** - In the Asian community, most Chinese celebrate the lunar new year.

"農曆新年快樂比較適合還是中式新年快樂 ?" - Standalone, this sentence does not make sense. I'll change it to a question:

要怎麼說比較合適 - 祝你農曆新年(Lunar New Year)快樂,還是祝你中式新年(Chinese New Year)快樂? Sounds better, but we usually say "祝你新年快樂", as the occurrence wouldn't be confused with the western new year, so neither "lunar" nor "Chinese" is necessary.

"祝在**论坛**(forum)上的各位，新春愉快，虎年行大運 ~ Same to you (你也是)!

Comment: Personally I don't like the term "Lunar New Year" when Chinese calendar is a lunisolar calendar.  Chinese New Year usually falls on the second new moon after the winter solstice. So you can see it is the Lunar + Solar by definition.

Comment: Yes, 農曆 literally means Farmer's calendar

Comment: @Archeosudoerus The dictionary says "**Lunar** - Of or relating to or associated with the **moon**"; "**Solar** - Relating to or derived from the **sun** or utilizing the energies of the sun"; "**Lunisolar**- Relating to or attributed to the **moon and the sun** or their mutual relations". Since "Chinese New Year usually falls on the second new **moon**...", won't the "Lunar" be more accurate?

Comment: @r13 it is not any new moon but the second after winter solstice(which is a 节气 ,Solar based term) in Chinese calendar.  It defines 24 Solar terms throughout the year based on the Sun's ecliptic longitude. Winter solstice is one of the 24 solar terms. The calendar says the Winter Solstice falls in the 11th month in Chinese calendar, so the first new moon after Winter Solstice should be the 12th month, hence the second new moon should be the beginning of the new year given there are 12 months in the calendar. Sometime there will be a leap month though, then it will be the third month after

Comment: @Archeosudoerus Note that 農曆 also called 陰曆. See this article for the difference between 陰曆 and 陽曆. https://nonglinyumu.com/agriculture/259658.html

Comment: @r13 Your link says "因為農曆並不是單純的陰曆，也不是陽曆，而是結合陽曆和陰曆而演變而成的“陰陽曆” and "中國傳統的歷法是結合了陽曆和陰曆的一種陰陽曆", which agree with my point of Lunisolar.

Comment: @Archeosudoerus You win the argument, but I think "lunar" is here to stay.

Comment: "Lunar New Year", is for distinguishing it from the Gregorian Calendar New Year; the Cosmic  purist's discomfort notwithstanding :)